# Rota laravel não funcioa em produção

Tags: php, laravel, apache, deploy, laravel-rotas

Estou com um problema, recentemente fiz deploy de um projeto laravel 6 em produção.

Tenho a seguinte rota:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('email', 'EmailController');
```

Localmente acesso http://localhost/projeto/public/email e acesso normalmente a rota, porém quando acesso em produção, retorna erro 404.

Meu .htaccess está assim

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Em produção você está tentando acessar também com `public/email` por que deveria ser `http://SeuendEndereço/email`

Comment: Estou sim... ip/projeto/email

Comment: E o que aparece?

Comment: Da 404, como se a rota nao existisse

Comment: Se você não configurou os seus sistema para abrir sem o public, na rota terá que ter também.  `http://SeuendEndereço/public/email`

Comment: @GlenysMitchell mas a rota tem, é justamente este o problema

Comment: Quais métodos você tem no controller?

Comment: Apenas os Defalut, index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy.  mas nem chega a ir na controller. não no servidor, no local funciona

Comment: Como você está utilizando Resource, verifica as rotas existentes com `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Ja olhei la, e está tudo certo apontando para o caminho certo. como eu disse no local funciona tudo, não é algo na rota ou na controller... acredito eu que seja algo em relação a configuração do servidor

Comment: Basicamente, eu ja fiz de tudo que é possivel... fiz um teste, ao fazer a rota Route::resource('/', 'EmailController'); ele chama minha controller corretamente, quando eu deixo assim Route::resource('email', 'EmailController'); nao e eu chamdo a public/email, da erro 404

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você está tendo o mesmo problema que tive um dia. Isso pode ser uma questão de configurar o virtual host, ou algo do tipo, onde o endereço [http://SeuendEndereço/](http://SeuendEndere%C3%A7o/) irá apontar para a pasta public dentro de seu projeto (definir a pasta public como DocumentRoot).

Eu não sei em qual sistema operacional o seu projeto está rodando, mas se não estiver com o virtual host configurado direito, quando você tentar acessar o endereço [http://SeuendEndereço/projeto/email](http://SeuendEndere%C3%A7o/projeto/email) ele irá procurar algum arquivo com o nome 'email' dentro da raiz do projeto, mesmo que esteja com a rota configurada, ocasionando assim o erro 404.

Segue um exemplo de configuração no apache rodando em um servidor linux

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projeto/public
    ServerName IpDoServidor

    <Directory /var/www/html/projeto/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```